# Placing MessagesEventArgs in class

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

In the code I wrote for a telegram bot I wanted to place this code:

```
Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs a
```

in the

```
Task.Run(() => { //code });
```

Because in the code I use `a.Messages.From.Username` and sometimes more than one user is using the bot and because of that I need to separate `a.Messages.From.Username`'s, but I couldn't find any way.

This is my code:

```
 void bot_OnMessage1(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs a)
 {
     Task.Run(() =>
     {
         string watermarkText = a.Message.Text;
         string fileName = "C:\\temp\\01.png";

         using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(fileName))
         {
             using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
             {
                 bmp.Save("c:\\temp\\" + a.Message.From.Username + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\" + a.Message.From.Username + ".png", FileMode.Open))
                 {
                     fs.CanTimeout.ToString();
                     FileToSend fileToSend = new FileToSend("c:\\temp\\" + a.Message.From.Username + ".png", fs);
                     var rep = bot.SendPhotoAsync(a.Message.From.Id, fileToSend, "این عکس را پست کنید").Result;
                 }
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: but you are already using the `a` variable inside the task code. what is your problem? compiler error? runtime exception?

Comment: Can you please clarify what are you trying to accomplish and what problem are you encountering?

Comment: that's actually [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46908506/1132334), several proposals are given including  doing everything in-memory to avoid concurrent file access.