# How to handle multiple users using same console application?

Tags: c#, azure, telegram

I'm new to programming and I wrote a telegram bot using console application and uploaded it to azure . i will give an example what happen while two users trying to use it at the same time:

***For example i have something like that:***

```
public static class MainMenu
    {
        public static bool run = false;

        public static async Task Main()
        {
            //some code
        }
        private static async void StartPosting()
        {
            run = true;
            while (run == true)
            {
                //do something
            }

        }
    }
```

when the first user start to use the StartPosting() method and while "run" is true he is inside this loop..
and when the other user starts the bot the run is still true for him ... i thaught that if i deploy my console application to azure evey user get his own session or something like that ..

what can i do to solve this problem ? i tried to search for answer in google but didn't found anything abut it .

Must note that I have a lot of variables like "run" and of course I have a database on azure where I store all the user data.

Comment: Not sure how to replicate this, but one thing I think will work is starting the StartPosting function in a new thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Ok lets say i making everything working with threads .. 
but lets say i have "getmessage" instead of run:
public static string getmessage= "";
and then i save the user message in getmessage and do something with that for some time .. 
when the second user will run the bot , he will replace the getmessage i guess?
and then while the first user still run the code will get wrong data ..
idk iam clueless

Comment: In that case you might need to think about data structures, maybe store the getmessage variable in a dictionary indexed by username

Comment: thanks for the advice bro , another question most of the code on telegram bot running with async methods .. when this async method executed , and another user call the same method at the same time while the first user still using it .. they will be in the same code again ? if its the case iam in big troubles lol

Comment: you need to use await when calling async functions

Comment: ok i found this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908506/how-to-handle-multiple-users-on-telegram-bot-in-c
i need to  keep context for each user somewhere , lol .. i will make a table for every user and read from there .. 
thank you bro hope i will figure it out quickly